# Why am I getting TypeError: 'vc' is an invalid keyword argument for this function error?

Tags: django, django-models

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.  Here is my Django model:

```
class VMMigrationEvent(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # DateTime because there may be multiple events in a day.
    dc = models.TextField(max_length=150),                 # data center
    destination_host = models.TextField(max_length=150),   # host migrated to.
    message = models.TextField(),                          # The message from virtual center.
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # DateTime because there may be multifple events in a day.
    user = models.TextField(max_length=150),       # The user logged into the virtual center that execute the migration.
    vc = models.TextField(max_length=150),         # virtual center
    vm = models.ForeignKey(VirtualMachine)         # The VirtualMachine record associated with this event.
```

And from the python console I do this:

```
>>> from cm.models import *
>>> dc='DCM01N-01'
>>> destination_host='auroravm2-1.example.com'
>>> message='my hovercraft is full of eels.'
>>> user='mister_gumby'
>>> vc='vca-001-s.example.com'
>>> vm='ads-108'
>>> vm_db_obj = VirtualMachine.objects.filter(name=vm).latest('create_date')
>>> vmme = VMMigrationEvent.objects.create(dc=dc, 
... destination_host=destination_host,
... message=message, user=user, vc=vc, vm=vm_db_obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/apps/man/man/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/man/man/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/apps/man/man/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'vc' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Why is `vc` invalid? It is a field in my model?

Comment: You added *tailing* comma's to your model fields. So that means these are *not* fields stored in the database, but 2-tuples that Django does not "interpret". Remove the comma's and run migrations.

Comment: doh!  I didn't see that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have commas after several of your field definitions: `vc`, but also `dc`, `destination_host` and `user`. This turns them into tuples, which can't be used as fields on the model.

Delete those commas

(Also, you probably meant CharField rather than TextField.)